# Why does my footnote not show up at the bottom of the page?

Tags: footnotes

I insert 3 footnotes so far. The first one and second one works well using the `\footnote{}`, but the third one does not show up at the bottom. The third one is in a display-math environment. Can anyone help me out of this?

This is the code of the third one.

```
\documentclass[12pt] {article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    \overline{c_t} & = \int_j c_{t_j}dj \\
    & = \int_j(R(1-\tau_{B_{t+1}})b_{{t+1}_j}+(1-\tau_{Y_t})w_{t_j}h_{t_j}+{Tr}_t-b_{{t+1}_j}-h_{{t+1}_j})dj \\
    & = R(1-\tau_B)b_t+(1-\tau_Y)y_t+Tr-b_{t+1}-h_{t+1} \\ \footnote{Here we assume balanced budget, therefore $Tr=0$. We also assume income taxes and bequest taxes are same in long run.}
    & = Rb_t+y_t-b_{t+1}-h_{t+1}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: Can't the footnote text be indicated in the body text instead? Explaining equations via footnotes seems a bit dangerous.

Comment: I think explaining the equation via footnotes would be more efficient because I changed the variables in one of the steps.

Answer (score 8):

Inside displayed equations, the usual `\footnote` command doesn't work. Instead, you need to (a) insert a `\footnotemark` directive where you want the footnote marker to be placed and (b) insert a `\footnotetext{...}` directive immediately after the end of the math material.

[image]

That said, and echoing @pluton's earlier remark, I don't think it's good practice to "bury" such information in a footnote. Instead, I think it's better to write an extra explanatory sentence or two *in the body of the document* right after the equation. Something like:

> The final equality in the preceding sequence of equations follows because we assume a balanced budget, therefore $\mathit{Tr}_t=0$, and because we further assume that income taxes and bequest taxes have the same effects in long run.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength\textheight{7cm} % just for this example

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    \bar{c}_t 
    &= \int_j c_{t_j}\,dj \\
    &= \int_j\bigl[R(1-\tau_{B_{t+1}})b_{{t+1}_j}
       +(1-\tau_{Y_t})w_{t_j}h_{t_j}+\mathit{Tr}_t-b_{{t+1}_j}
       -h_{{t+1}_j}\bigr]\,dj \\
    &= R(1-\tau_B)b_t+(1-\tau_Y)y_t+\mathit{Tr}_t-b_{t+1}-h_{t+1} \\ 
    \footnotemark  
    &= Rb_t+y_t-b_{t+1}-h_{t+1}\,.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}\footnotetext{Here we assume balanced budget, 
therefore $\mathit{Tr}_t=0$. We also assume income taxes and 
bequest taxes are same in long run.}

Bla bla bla \dots
\end{document}
```